# send emails using SQL Server triggers (the recipient email address is dynamic according to a client)

Tags: sql-server, eventtrigger

I need to create a trigger to send emails to clients whenever a record was inserted. The client's emails are in another table "B" within the same database so I will need to create a trigger that will pick the email address from table "B" then using the primary key I should be able to match the two tables.
How do I call this table and fetch these emails into my trigger and use them as the "recipient email"?

Different clients have different emails so the emails will be dynamic?
Thank you

example code

```
-- Create an insert trigger
create trigger sendEmail on
tblVendTrans
for insert
as
 
DECLARE @sendEmail varchar(50);
DECLARE @PPL varchar(50);
DECLARE @PPL2 varchar(50);

select @PPL2 = (select strVendName FROM dbSample.dbo.tblVendors);
select @PPL = s.strVendName from inserted s;
Select @sendEmail = (select strEmail FROM dbSample.dbo.tblVendors WHERE @PPL= @PPL2);


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Send Profile',
@recipients = @sendEmail,
@subject = 'Database Record Added',
@body_format='HTML',
@body =  @sendEmail,
@attach_query_result_as_file = 0;
 
go
```

Comment: Better don't send e-mails from trigger - any communication error or similar may create lockups and so on. You could create some intermediate table (mail queue), fill it (from, to and other required fields) in trigger and send e-mails from scheduled job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
```

and for parameter @recipients select your email from another table that you wants
and for @body parameter you can create it dynamically

i wish its helpful for you

Comment: Thank you , under the same concept check what i am requesting under the @recipients (is there a presise querry that is used to fetch this emails )               
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
"@profile_name = 'testProfile',"
"@recipients = **fetch recipient's email from another table**"
"@subject = 'Database Record Added',"
"@body_format='HTML',"
"@body =  'test body',"
"@attach_query_result_as_file = 0;"
 
go

Comment: that is true you can declare parameter before EXEC and use this parameter under the code that you wrote